# Show that $f(x)=\alpha x$ for some $\alpha \in R$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for some $f: R \rightarrow R$ such that $f$ is continuous at $0$.Show that $f(x)=\alpha x$ for some $\alpha \in R$. Hint: show that $f(nx) = nf(x)$, then show $f$ is continuous on $R$. Then show that $f(x)/x = f(1)$ for all rational $x$.

How can I show $f(nx)=nf(x)$?? I am stuck with the first hint, so I can't show any attempt.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your hints are out of order. Continuity should come last. Integers, then rationals. Then continuity allows you to conclude the desired formula holds for all real numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By mathematical induction.

(1) It is obviously true for $n=1$.

(2) If $f(kx)=kf(x)$, then $$f((k+1)x)=f(kx+x)=f(kx)+f(x)=kf(x)+f(x)=(k+1)f(x)$$

Answer (score 3):

This is what do you want,
$$f(m)=f(1+1+...+1)=f(1)+f(1)+...+f(1)=mf(1),m\in\mathbb{z^+}.$$
Deduce,
$$f(1)=f(\frac{n}{n})=f(\frac{1}{n})+f(\frac{1}{n})+...+f(\frac{1}{n})=nf(\frac{1}{n}),n\in\mathbb{z^+}.$$
Hence,
$$f(\frac{m}{n})=\frac{m}{n}f(1)$$
Hence, use $\mathbb{Q}$ dense in $\mathbb R$ and $f$ is continuous. we get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for hint.

Answer (score 1):

Notice if we let $y=x$, then

$$ f(2x) = 2 f(x) $$

Now, let $x=2x'$, then

$$ f(4x') = 2 f(2x') = 4 f(x') $$

Continuing in this fashion youll get $f(nx) = nf(x) $